# How to set database column as "Sparse" when using EF Code First Fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, dbcontext, sparse-matrix

I am working with a system that is using EF code first and I would like to use a number of SQL Server sparse columns on a table.  My current solution is to drop the table created by EF and re-add via a script during the database initialization.  Is this something that can be configured with Fluent API in a class inherited from EntityTypeConfiguration or other means?

Comment: I didn't try it but what happens if you use `.HasColumnType("INT SPARSE")`?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka  I tried .HasColumnType("INT SPARSE") and it threw `(182,6) : error 0040: The Type int sparse is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification.`  Thank you for the idea.

Comment: Well, it probably means that sparse columns are not supported.

Comment: Or the column name is escaped without your knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Entity Frameworks migrations, you can issue a SQL statement like this in the [Up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.up.aspx) method for the migration that adds the sparse column:

```
Sql("alter table TableName alter column ColumnName int sparse");
```

Even if you don't use migrations, any one-time execution of `dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` with the same SQL will work.

Neither way is as nice as if you could explicitly configure the type through EF, but they're still better than dropping and replacing the entire table.

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported in EF Core 6.0 as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#support-for-sql-server-sparse-columns)

> This can now be configured using IsSparse in OnModelCreating. For example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<ForumModerator>()
        .Property(e => e.ForumName)
        .IsSparse();
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30287592)